# Run console function across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

Kind of a difficult one to explain and I'm not 100% sure this can be achieved in the console or if another method would be required.

Step by step of what I want to do:

- Step 1 - Click anchor `i` out of list of anchors (for loop) and go to new page
- Step 2 - Click first anchor on second page and go to third page
- Step 3 - Click button and go back to the first page.
- Step 4 - Repeat step 1-3, this time `i` is the second anchor taking you to a new page. and so on until all anchors on page 1 have been clicked and step 2 and 3 have happened for each.

In my head I can write this as a step by step, but I'm not sure how I would automate this process in the way I would like to.

This is the code I'm starting with:

```
// Step 1 - Page 1
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < $('a').length; i++) {
    $('a').eq(i).click();
}

// Step 2 - Page 2
$('a').eq(0).click();

// Step 3 - Page 3
$('button').click();

// Step 4 onward - Click next anchor in for loop and repeat step 2 and 3 until there are no anchors left on page 1 to click
```

Any help or guidance would be great - I've tried Googling but I'm not entirely sure what I'm actually looking for!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If pages 1, 2 or 3 are totally different documents (i.e. going from page 1 to 2 requires the browser to do a full redirect), the only way I can think of is carrying the anchor to be clicked next in a URL query param. E.g.:

```
// page 1
<a id="anchor1" href="www.example.com/page2?nextAnchor=anchor2>Anchor 1</a>
<a id="anchor2" href="www.example.com/page2?nextAnchor=anchor3>Anchor 2</a>
<a id="anchor3" href="www.example.com/page2>Anchor 3</a>
```

If you carry `?nextAnchor=anchor2` through the pages until you get back to page 1, you can get `nextAnchor` value in your page 1's script so you have the exact ID of the anchor that must be clicked next. The process repeats until you have no `nextAnchor` value (which happens in the last anchor).

Answer (score 0):

Simple- While HTTP is stateless, you've got Cookies, URI parameters, sockets, and you may even be able to use a web worker if you open your pages in an iframe if they are on the same domain.

Using URI parameters (i.e. `http://domain.com/?use_loop_script&step=2&current_anchor=3&callback=click_link(x)`) might be the simplest way to go, so long as you can have access to scripting all pages.

Then you can simply plug a function on each page and check if `use_loop_script` is present in the URI and use the number set in the URI to execute your function `click_link(i)` or something to that nature.

You'll need to use the URI to keep track of your steps in order to execute the appropriate function (click an anchor, click a button, etc.)

iframes are treated as separate documents, and as long as the are on the same domain, your JavaScript can check if that document is ready and click any links from the main page if you want it to. So you wouldn't even really need URI parameters at all or even loading any scripts on the subsequent pages, if you simply access the DOM of the iframe.

Comment: Remember, you'll need to run this script after the page loads, so either put your script on the bottom of the page or set it up in a document.ready() (jQuery) or equivalent method.